# Serial communication between rpi zero w and laptop running python over usb

Tags: pi-zero-w

new rpi user here! I am trying to make a HCI device using a rpi zero w and I want to connect the rpi as a usb device to my laptop and use usb to stream data. On the laptop side, there will be a python script that reads the data. In future, I want connect multiple rpis using a usb hub, but for now would like to test with just one. I have seen tutorials on using the rpi zero w as a usb gadget and then using ssh to connect to the pi. My question is can you setup the pi to be plug and play (after a one-time initial setup) and read the data using the python script using pyserial like you would from an arduino?

Comment: Why not just use a USB serial adapter that handles 3v3 and talk direct to the Pi over serial? Failing that have a look at https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/serial-gadget Failing that Bluetooth?

Comment: like a FTDI adapter? I want to power it as well as communicate with it via a single cable, mainly for ease of use and design considerations. I am trying to figure out if it is possible or not.

Comment: Did you look at the Adafruit site I posted?

Comment: Yes I looked at it but didnt get the time to try it out... plus if i am not wrong, that method requires a rj45 cable? In that case, I currently dont have one. I maybe wrong though..

Comment: @Andyroo I setup the pi as a serial gadget as outlined in the adafruit link you sent and am now able to login to pi via usb serial using putty. Now if I want to send a stream of data from the rpi to a python program running in the pc, how do i do that? Sorry if the solution is very obvious... I could not find much on this

Comment: Python has a serial module but I would use the extended version https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial simplest connection for send and revive is https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports but this is raw data handling - no error checking, retries or control. Interesting thought https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=131558.0 and https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/12/framing-in-serial-communications or even https://pypi.org/project/xmodem/  General program forums should be able to help at this point.